# How to fix FontAwesome icons being huge on page load in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After a lot of searching, I can't seem to find a solution for this.
I'm using forawesome icons on my main page, and on load they are huge for a short period of time.

here is an example: https://makeyka.herokuapp.com/

I've tried

```js
import {config} from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
config.autoAddCss = false;
```

then trying to add the css with no luck

Comment: Stumbled over this issue myself. Interestingly I tried hiding all the icons using some hiding class applied on icons' container to be removed as soon as the window load has finished. This didn't help either, I assume because of loading fontawesome stuff lazily as well.

Answer (score 6):

Turn off autoAddCss:

```
import { config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
config.autoAddCss = false
```

Load in CSS directly in SCSS file:

```
@import 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles'
```

And in your style put this:

```
<style jsx global>{`
  ...

  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic');

  ${dom.css()}

  ...
`}</style>
```

please follow the link: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/server-side-rendering

Answer (score 4):

Basically this question is abut React.js. However I was stumbling over the very same issue in context of Vue.js. This solution of mine is basically meant to work with Vue.js in context of single-file components.

Insert this code in your entry code file:

```
import { config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
config.autoAddCss = false;
```

Now, prepend another block addressing the required file to any existing `<style>` block in your root element's component:

```
<style src="@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css"></style>
```

Answer (score 2):

class .hero-section-content-intro(container for all font Icons) has width: 300;

until CSS file for Icon is not loaded all icons takes width : 300 (of parent)

you need to handle this case to resolve issue.

add font-size for icons.